# Panel not displayed in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

```
<form runat="server" id="from1">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSiteQuestions">
                >>>>> CONTROLS removed for brevity <<<<<
                <asp:Button ID="btnContinue" runat="server" Text="Continue" OnClick="btnContinue_Click" ValidationGroup="Questions" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlNotRequired" runat="server" Visible="false">
        Sorry you do not qualify.
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlAdditionalDetails" Visible="false">
                    <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="ValidationSummary1" />
                        Name
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="ValidatorName" ControlToValidate="ContactFormNameTextBox" ErrorMessage="Name is required" CssClass="ErrorClass">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" />

                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="ABC123"></div>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" Text="Confirm" OnClick="button1_Click" />
            </asp:Panel>

</form>
```

I have the above form and decided to add an update panel. When a user clicks Continue, it goes to a database and determines if the user qualifies. If not pnlNotRequired message is displayed otherwise pnlAdditionalDetails is displayed.

Everything is/was working until i added the update panel. So removing the UP has everything working.

I tried adding a `trigger` but i didnt fully understand how it should be configured as i dont completely understand why this is occurring?

No Javascript errors listed either. Anyway to overcome this issue?

Comment: Update panel should cover all panels.  Add property to update panel "UpdateMode='Conditional'" than add trigger block.

Comment: Will try this out shortly. Do you have an example of how to the trigger block should be added as before when I added it I got strange errors or I wasn't sure which control id I need to target or event to add?

Comment: In this situation i think u should give "btnContinue". You can refer [here](http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/updatepanel-with-triggers-in-Asp-Net-1090.aspx)

Comment: Moving the end updatePanel tag so its surrounding all the code resolved the continue click issue and displays the panel but the captcha no longer displays? I didnt need the Trigger code as it was working but even adding the trigger didnt resolve showing the captcha?

Comment: I just changed the UpdateMode='Conditional' to 'Always' and that did the trick to display the captcha. @ErdemOzdemir considering you pushed me towards the right direction, if you make this into an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update panel should cover all panels. Add property to update panel "UpdateMode='Conditional'" than add trigger block